# Difficulty making just one Line3D object in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm animating 3D line object similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572718/3904031) which is really from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/02/16/animating-the-lorentz-system-in-3d/).

I want to animate just *one line*, not many lines, and I can't figure out what is happening here. I think that it's related to how `sum()` is working.

How can I make just one, and why does this fail?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import cnames

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection='3d')
colors = plt.cm.jet([0.3, 0.7])

LINES = sum([ax.plot([],[],[], '-', c=c) for c in colors], [])
line = LINES[0]
line.set_data([], [])                 # THIS WORKS

LINES = [ax.plot([],[],[], '-', c=colors[0])]
line = LINES[0]
line.set_data([], [])                 # THIS FAILS
```

So I can reduce my question further:

```
a = [1]
print "type(a[0]): ", type(a[0])   # expect <type 'int'>

b = [ax.plot([],[],[], '-', c=colors[0])]
print "type(b[0]): ", type(b[0])   # expect <class 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D'>
```

gives

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: In your first example, `LINES` is a `list` of `Line3D` objects, in the second, it's a `list` of `list`s.  So, in the failing code, `line` is a `list` constaining a single `Line3D` object.  You try to call `set_data` on that `list` object and python tells you that `list` doesn't have that function. You could make it work by doing `line = LINES[0][0]`, but I can't grasp the context of what you're doing here to get the overall objective.  The code seems rather complicated to just animate one 3D sparkline.

Comment: I don't understand *why* `LINES` in the second part is a `list` of `list`s, but only a `list` in the first part. If `a=[1]` then `type(a[0])` gives `int`.  But if `a=[ax.plot(..)]`, then `type(a[0])` gives `list`. Maybe I should rewrite the question to that. Am I just missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: I added the "reduced" version of the question. Once I get this working I'll look for simpler ways to plot @JRichardSnape. But as long as I don't understand something I can't let go of it.

Comment: It basically is, as you suggest, what `sum` is doing.  I've added a more complete answer below (I'll post the gif when I can get imagemagick working...).  Try this: `sum([['a'],['long'],[string]],[])` vs. `[['a']]`.  That should illustrate what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point here is that `ax.plot` returns a `list` of `Line3D` objects (even though it's a list with a single member in your examples), not the `Line3D object itself`.

Therefore, in your first example, `LINES` is a `list` of `Line3D` objects, in the second, it's a `list` of `list`s.  So, in the failing code, `line` is a `list` constaining a single `Line3D` object.  You try to call `set_data` on that `list` object and python tells you that `list` doesn't have that function. You could make it work by doing `line = LINES[0][0]`, or simply doing

```
LINES = ax.plot([],[],[], '-', c=colors[0])[0]
```

---

To take your [example code here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/02/16/animating-the-lorentz-system-in-3d/) and make it plot only a single line change the lines:

```
# set up lines and points
lines = sum([ax.plot([], [], [], '-', c=c)
             for c in colors], [])
pts = sum([ax.plot([], [], [], 'o', c=c)
           for c in colors], [])
```

to read

```
# set up lines and points
lines = ax.plot([], [], [], '-', c=colors[0])
pts = ax.plot([], [], [], 'o', c=colors[0])
```

The `sum` is just a way to append all the members of the comprehension into one big list.  The change above changes from having one line per color in the colormap to having a single line.

Comment: Bingo! OK it's very clear now. And I feel a little silly not having figured this out myself. Thanks for taking the time to explain clearly what is happening! Next step (and possibly question) will be on simplification of the animation. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - another pair of eyes on a problem often helps :)